# Java 8 stream - cast list items to type of subclass

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of `ScheduleContainer` objects and in the stream each element should be casted to type `ScheduleIntervalContainer`. Is there a way of doing this?

```
final List<ScheduleContainer> scheduleIntervalContainersReducedOfSameTimes

final List<List<ScheduleContainer>> scheduleIntervalContainerOfCurrentDay = new ArrayList<>(
        scheduleIntervalContainersReducedOfSameTimes.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ScheduleIntervalContainer::getStartDate).reversed())
            .filter(s -> s.getStartDate().withTimeAtStartOfDay().isEqual(today.withTimeAtStartOfDay())).collect(Collectors
                .groupingBy(ScheduleIntervalContainer::getStartDate, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.<ScheduleContainer> toList()))
            .values());
```

Comment: This is unclear. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You asked exactly the same question four hours ago.

Comment: Simplest approach is to use a method reference: `.map( ScheduleIntervalContainer.class::cast )`, as suggested in a comment by Jon Skeet below, and in a much later answer to a related, but different question by the OP.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It's possible, but you should first consider if you need casting at all or just the function should operate on subclass type from the very beginning.

Downcasting requires special care and you should first check if given object can be cast down by:

```
object instanceof ScheduleIntervalContainer
```

Then you can cast it nicely by:

Use functional method to cast like `ScheduleIntervalContainer.class::cast`

So, the whole flow should look like:

```
collection.stream()
    .filter(ScheduleIntervalContainer.class::isInstance)
    .map(ScheduleIntervalContainer.class::cast)
    // other operations
```

Comment: isn't there any collect (like in scala) that filter and cast at the same time?

Answer (score 39):

Do you mean you want to cast each element?

```
scheduleIntervalContainersReducedOfSameTimes.stream()
                                            .map(sic -> (ScheduleIntervalContainer) sic)
                // now I have a Stream<ScheduleIntervalContainer>
```

Or you could use a method reference if you feel it is clearer

```
                                            .map(ScheduleIntervalContainer.class::cast)
```

On a performance note; the first example is a non-capturing lambda so it doesn't create any garbage, but the second example is a capturing lambda so could create an object each time it is classed.

Comment: Would a method reference work here? `map(ScheduleIntervalContainer.class::cast)` Will give it a go for myself when I can. Not sure it's more readable, but I'm intrigued :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have used it before but seems needlessly clever/obscure.

Comment: map(ScheduleIntervalContainer.class::cast) -> this was exactly what I need - thanks!