# Java multiple subtypes and supertypes in the same List

Tags: java, android, generics, inheritance, arraylist

I have a superclass `Animal` and a subclass `Dog`. In a third class I have a `List` which accepts both subtype and supertype objects at the same time.

```
public class foo{
    public ArrayList<Animal> animals;
    public ArrayList<Animal> copyOfAnimals;
    
    public foo(ArrayList<Animal> a){
        animals=a;
        copyOfAnimals = new ArrayList<>(a);
   }
}
```

Although this works fine, I cannot call `foo(dog);` which is an `ArrayList<Dog>`. This gives an error.

**If I implement wildcards,**

```
public class foo{
    public ArrayList<? extends Animal> animals;
    public ArrayList<Animal> copyOfAnimals;
    
    public foo(ArrayList<? extends Animal> a){
        animals=a;
        copyOfAnimals = new ArrayList<>(a);
   }
}
```

will result in another error where I cannot perform `animals.add(anotherAnimal)` which is important in my case.

Is there another solution to this? Is making `Animal` abstract a solution?

### Update

class `foo` is an android `Recyclerview` adapter class which is meant to show a list of both `Animal` and `Dog` and any other subtype.

Comment: foo (new ArrayList<Dog> dog); is not valid Java syntax, which causes the error.

Comment: @Stultuske That is not the point though. I'll update the question with the correct syntax. The error I'm talking about still exists.

Comment: Should the class `foo` be generic? e.g. `Foo<Dog>` ?

Comment: @sdgfsdh not sure, why?

Comment: The thing is, `ArrayList<Dog>` ***is not a kind of*** `ArrayList<Animal>`. You can put any kind of animals into a `ArrayList<Animal>`, but you can only put dogs into `ArrayList<Dog>`. If you say that you are never going to insert any items into the lists, then fine, you can fix your code by also adding wildcards on the declaration of the fields.

Comment: A very good discussion about PECS (Producer-Extends-Consumer-Super) is here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super

Comment: @Sweeper so I cannot make a generic list that accepts any subtype? or maybe a generic Superclass? or abstract superclass?.... as possible workarounds

Comment: please show all relevant code. Now you say that 'foo(dog);' is giving "an error", but you don't state which error, neither do you show how dog is declared/initialized.

Comment: @user7331538 You _can_ assign a `ArrayList<T>` where `T` is `Animal` or one of its subclasses to a variable of type `ArrayList<? extends Animal>`, _but_, you won't be able to add anything to it. And you _can_ assign a `ArrayList<T>` where `T` is `Animal` or one of its superclasses to a variable of type `ArrayList<? super Animal>`, but you can only take `Objects` out of it.

Comment: @user7331538 I think you should explain more clearly what the class `foo` is for. Otherwise you are walking into an http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @sdgfsdh class foo is an android Recyclerview adapter class which is meant to show a list of both `Animal` and `Dog` and any other subtype.

Comment: then why not store a list of animal?

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear, but here is my general recommendation.

1. Since you expect to store any type that implements `Animal`, you should use `List<Animal>`.
2. If you need to [get all elements that have a particular subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743525/java-8-stream-cast-list-items-to-type-of-subclass), you should generate that list from the list of `Animal`. It is *derived data*. You can do that like this:

```java
var dogs = animals.stream()
    .filter(obj -> obj instanceof Dog)
    .map(obj -> (Dog) obj)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And attempting to design `Foo`:

```java
public class Foo {
    private List<Animal> animals;

    public List<Dog> getDogs() {
        return animals.stream()
            .filter(obj -> obj instanceof Dog)
            .map(obj -> (Dog) obj)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public Foo(List<Animal> animals) {
        this.animals = new ArrayList<>(animals);
    }
}
```